# A word to describe hidden sexual intent... play on words

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word to describe hidden sexual intention? e.g "Haha I was reading your profile and ...you seem pretty tight ;-)"  How would I respond with a word that describes double meaning of a sentence to actually mean a sexual advance on the sly? Does that make sense? A play on words..

Answer (score 9):

The one I am most familiar with is a *double entendre*. Merriam-Webster gives

> ## [**double entendre**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%20entendre)
>
> **noun** dou·ble en·ten·dre \ˈdüb-əl-äⁿ-ˈtäⁿd(-rə); ˈdə-bəl-än-ˈtänd(-rə)\
>
> **1**
>   :  ambiguity of meaning arising from language that lends itself to more than one interpretation
>    **2**
>   :  a word or expression capable of two interpretations with one usually risqué

Answer (score 6):

The phrase Sexual Innuendo is what I would say they're using.

> The term sexual innuendo has acquired a specific meaning, namely that of a "risqué" double entendre by playing on a possibly sexual interpretation of an otherwise innocent uttering. For example: "We need to go deeper" can be seen as either a request for further inquiry, or a request to go deeper into an intimate part.

[Innuendo on Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innuendo)

Answer (score 2):

The word is Double-Entendre. This can refer to any sentence with two meanings, but most often is used when one meaning of a sentence is innocent and the other is sexual.

If it has an unintentional sexual undertone, you might call it a Freudian Slip, implying that someone's sexuality accidentally expressed itself.

A colloquial phrase for this is "... if you know what I mean." This is useful for when you want to call to attention the sexual meaning a sentence can have.